# .ZIP filenames with spaces not working correctly with creation and unzipping batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, zip

I have finished writing a short batch script that will automatically unzip and delete any zipped files in the downloads folder.

I works perfectly except when presented with zip files containing a space in their name.

I can't say for sure where the problem is so I will put the whole script here as it is fairly short.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\
del /q search_result.txt


for /r %%i in (*.zip) do (
echo %%~nxi >> search_result.txt
)
for /f %%i in ("search_result.txt") do set asdf=%%~zi
if %asdf% gtr 0 (
goto unzipAgain
)
end
:unzipAgain
set /p zippedFile=< search_result.txt

Call :UnZipFile "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%zippedFile:~0,-4%" "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%zippedFile%"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
cd /d %~dp0
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%

del C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%zippedFile%
cd C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\
findstr /V %zippedFile% search_result.txt > newfile.txt
xcopy newfile.txt search_result.txt /y >nul
del newfile.txt /f /q >nul

for /f %%i in ("search_result.txt") do set asdf=%%~zi
if %asdf% gtr 0 (
goto unzipAgain
)

del search_result.txt
```

TIA, Evyn

*n.b The VBScript is not mine and I do not know how it works, I simply used it in conjunction with my own code*

Comment: That is a whole lot of code to do one very small task. I realize half of it is used to create the VBscript but all the other lines of batch file code could be minimized into just a few lines.  If you are on Windows 7 or above I would highly suggest you use Powershell to do the unzipping as that can literally be one line of code.

Comment: I'm surprised it works properly with files containing no spaces as well! Try reading the `For` command help, _(especially `UseBackQ` and `Tokens` or `Delims`)_. You should also learn to protect strings by doublequoting where possible.

Comment: I tested the Vbscript with files that had spaces in the name and it worked fine. I didn't use your convoluted batch code.

Comment: If you are going to stick with using the Vbscript, I would suggest you rewrite it so it takes arguments into the script when you run it instead of recreating the script with the batch file variables for every file you need to process.  Your current batch file is SUPER inefficient.  Not to mention you are making continuous CALLS without ever returning to the parent process before making another CALL.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a `FOR /R` because your script will never process a zip file within a sub-folder of the current directory.  If you are just processing files in a single folder then you don't need the `/R` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest with you, I can't say in my wildest dreams I would try to code what you did like that.  You literally made a mountain out of mole hill. You couldn't have possibly made it much harder on yourself.  I think once you see these three code examples you will realize why you should adhere to the K.I.S.S. principle.

The Vbscript code you have works perfectly fine with spaces. It was probably something in your batch file code that was screwing something up. You can greatly simplify your code by using one single `FOR` command and just create the Vbscript once. I changed the VBscript to accept command line arguments.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Batch\unzip"
CD /D "%source%"
call :createVBS "unzip.vbs"

FOR %%G IN (*.zip) DO (
    cscript //nologo "%vbs%" "%source%\%%~nG" "%source%\%%~G"
    del "%%~G"
)
del "%vbs%" 2>nul
exit /b

:CreateVBS
set "vbs=%~1"
del "%vbs%" 2>nul
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(objArgs(0)) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(objArgs(0))
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(objArgs(1)).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(objArgs(0)).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
```

Powershell has been out for around 10 years or so. There have been a few ways to unzip files within Powershell since then.  This first version will work if you are on a version of Powershell before Version 5.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Batch\unzip"
CD /D "%source%"

for %%G in (*.zip) do (
    powershell -command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('%%~G', '.\%%~nG')"
    del "%%~G"
)
```

In version 5 of Powershell the code was greatly simplified with a new cmdlet.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Batch\unzip"
CD /D "%source%"

for %%G in (*.zip) do (
    powershell Expand-Archive '%%~G' -DestinationPath '.\%%~nG'
    del "%%~G"
)
```

So you can see how calling out to Powershell has greatly reduced the amount of code you need in your batch file.